# Set DNS server in resolve.conf using wicd

Tags: ubuntu, dns, wicd

**Short version:** How do I get a "nameserver" to be permanently saved in resolve.conf when using wicd for networking?

**Long Version**: I got the following error message after attempting to update apt-get in Ubuntu Server:

```
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/zesty/InRelease  Could not resolve 'ca.archive.ubuntu.com'
```

Looked like a DNS error, so I checked out /etc/resolve.conf:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

I manually edited the file and added:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

to the end. Ran "apt-get update" and everything went smoothly.

The problem of course is that resolve.conf gets clobbered a lot, so I tried to manually set the DNS server using WICD. I went into wicd-curses, selected the wireless network I use, and set the following options:

```
[X] Use Static DNS           [ ] Use global DNS servers
DNS domain: google.com
Search domain: 
DNS server 1: 8.8.8.8
DNS server 2: 8.8.4.4
DNS server 3:
```

and reboot my computer. Opened up resolve.conf and saw:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
search google.com
```

Tried apt-get update anyway, but it failed with the same error from earlier.

Next I tried opening /etc/wicd/dhclient.conf.template and appending the following:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
```

but that had no effect on resolve.conf.

I don't mess around with networking very often (or at least not at this level); is there some fundamental mistake or flaw I'm making in setting a DNS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `resolvconf(8)` is assuming `systemd-resolved` is running and writes the `nameserver 127.0.0.53` entry to `/etc/resolv.conf`. You may want to check what `/etc/resolvconf.conf` contains. See also `man 8 resolvconf` and `man 5 resolvconf.conf`. If `systemd-resolved.service` is running, you may also want to disable that.

(Or, perhaps take a step back, and reconsider if you really are unsatisfied with the way Ubuntu handles network settings out of the box.)

Comment: Disabling system-resolved.service and rebooting did the trick. I still get a "Failed to connect to http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release" message when logging in, but every connection attempt after that works fine. I'm also going to take your comment to heart. I started using wicd way back in 2011 when I was unsatisfied with how wireless network setting were handled in ubuntu; it's time to update my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

In wicd Ubuntu Network Manager please find and uncheck the option of automatically fetch DNS server and set it manually to `8.8.8.8` & `8.8.4.4`

The Network manager is fetching DNS address from upstream ISP and updating it.

As you're using GUI tools for network manager you can update the DNS preference option from GUI .

Find the procedure and images https://askubuntu.com/questions/87468/how-to-specify-dns-ip-in-wicd